# _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I need to display an image but the terminal always returns :
TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist

I don't understand why because at the beginning it worked but when I modified other elements (without modifying my image) it started to bug.

```
fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.title("Cookie Game.py")
fenetre.geometry("650x550")
global_color = equ()
color_b, color_f  = global_color[0],global_color[1]
fenetre.minsize(625,525)
fenetre.config(background = color_b)

...

box_centre = Frame(fenetre, bg=color_b)
box1 = Frame(box_centre, bg= color_b)

txt_1 = Label(box1, text="Cookie Game", font=("Courier New",50), bg=color_b, fg="white")
txt_1.pack() #side =LEFT / =RIGHT /  =BOTTOM / =TOP 

your_gold = Entry(box1, font=("Helvetica Neu",25), bg=color_b, fg="#F7B719",bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
your_gold.pack()
box1.pack(side=TOP)

#image
larg = 300 #largeur img
haut =  300 #hauteur img
img = PhotoImage(file="cookie_1.png").zoom(50).subsample(100)
canvas = Canvas(box_centre, height=haut, width=larg, bg=color_b, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)

canvas.create_image(larg/2, haut/2, image=img)     # <-- line error

canvas.pack(pady = 25)
box_centre.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky=W)
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Add `master=box_centre` to `PhotoImage(file="cookie_1.png")`

Comment: Are you creating more than one instance of `Tk`? Have you done any research? We get a question like this almost once a week.

Comment: It works, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter` uses `tcl` different interpreters for each `Tk()` window. Each interpreter has its own memory. All of the children of the window are managed by the same `tcl` interpreter. When you don't pass in the `master` parameter `tkinter` uses the first created `tcl` interpreter.

Consider this example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root_1 = tk.Tk() # Note this is the default root now
root_2 = tk.Tk()

label_1 = tk.Label(text="Hi") # By default `master=root_1`
label_1.pack()

tk_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="...") # By default `master=root_1`
label_2 = tk.Label(root_2, image=tk_img) # We are trying to use something that doesn't exist in this tcl interpreter.
label_2.pack()
```

Note that we haven't passed in a `master` for `label_1` and `tk_img`. The first argument of tkinter widgets are usually the `master` so for `label_2` the master is `root_2`.

Tkinter can't create a widget without a master as the widget must live in a tcl interpreter so it tries to guess which `tcl` interpreter it should use (always the first one that has been created). Therefore, the master for `label_1` and `tk_img` will be `root_1`. So when we tell the second interpreter that we want it to use the variable `tk_img` (on this line `label_2 = tk.Label(root_2, image=tk_img)`), it fails as the second interpreter (for the second window) doesn't know about the other interpreter.